# Map the values in object with the given value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am new to the react, Here I have one array of object which is like

```
 const bgStatus =
   [{
     Id: "809"
     Name: "PRE"
    Description: "PRE"
    Value: "VP:PRE"
    },
    {
     Id: "809"
     Name: "CLO"
    Description: "CLO"
    Value: "VP:CLO"
    },
    {
     Id: "809"
     Name: "BU"
    Description: "BU"
    Value: "VP:BU"
    }
    ]
```

Now , In this I have one method through which I get the value which is `VP:PRE or VP:BU or VP:CLO`

Now, I have the following function

```
getmsg = (bgSt, tobeChange, current) => { 

return `Are you sure you want to change to ${tobeChange}? not possible to go ${current} `

}
```

Now, In this both the status `tobeChange` and `current` comes in a `VP:PRE` in this format. Now, I want to use the `Description` from that array for that value like for `VP:PRE` , it should be 'PRE' in the return value. Now ,

I have one solution which is like creating a key value map and then map it. But, I can not hard code that values over here.

So, and also don't want to use the includes or contains things.

Result which I want - When I am calling the function

```
getmsg this time in params I am passing , tobeChange is `"VP:PRE"`, current is "VP_BU" and bgStatus is the array of object.
```

Now in return I should get this message ,

```
`Are you sure you want to change to PRE not possible to go BU `
```

The values VP_PRE should get replaced with the description PRE

Comment: to be honest, as a reader i did not understand what you want to extract from `bgSt `

Comment: Can you append your desired result?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with react and is purely about javascript.

Comment: Yeah just a movement I will update the result I want.

Comment: @a_m_dev Please check my latest code

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov please check it I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are always getting the two variables :

- tobeChange=VP:something_to_change
- current=VP:something

It has nothing to do with react it is javascript traitement 
I suggest you use the function **split** here is an example :

```js
getmsg = (tobeChange, current) => { 
toChange=tobeChange.split(":")
tobeChange=toChange[1]

curr=current.split(":")
current=curr[1]

return `Are you sure you want to change to ${tobeChange}? not possible to go ${current} `

}

tobeChange="VP:something_to_change"
current="VP:something_current"

console.log(getmsg(tobeChange, current))
```